# How to run debug in view django with Atom python-debugger?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, atom-editor

I'm using Atom for development python. I created a simple project with python and Django. I have already installed

> python-debugger

But how can I run debug it in view of django.

Answer (score 0):

Django have a debugger enviroment:

1. $ mkdir myvenv
2. $ cd myvenv
3. $ python3 -m venv myvenv
4. $ source myvenv/bin/activate

Now your prompt is: `(myvenv)diego@AspireM1640 ~/www/myvenv $`

Go to your project folder, run the server debug: `python manage.py runserver` or for intranet with IP:`python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.33:8000`